# How does the program get the terminal directory?

Tags: terminal

When running a program from the terminal, say i type `make` how does make know the directory which was in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "current directory" isn't a property of the terminal in the first place; it's tracked by the kernel per-process and **every** process (even those not associated with a terminal) has its own "working directory", which is automatically inherited down by child processes.

Any process can use the [chdir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call (POSIX) or [SetCurrentDirectory()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) (Windows) to change its own working directory. Use [getcwd()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) (POSIX) or [GetCurrentDirectory()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) (Windows) to retrieve the current directory.

(The terminal app does have its own "working directory", but this only influences where the shell will *start* and doesn't get updated when you `cd` around. Nearly all graphical apps stay at $HOME the whole time.)

---

If you want to find out the working directory of some other process, Linux lets you look at `/proc/<pid>/cwd`, but this is generally *not* something that your program should be doing.

Comment: In a simple c++ program, how can i get the path which was in the terminal which ran my program

Comment: I don't know the C++ conventions, but in plain C you would use the getcwd() function in POSIX or GetCurrentDirectory() in Win32 API.

Comment: Looks like the modern C++ convention is `std::filesystem::current_path()`, or at least that's what google search results are saying.